# How to decode JSON with three dots on value

Tags: php

I did some research but I can't seem to find the answer.

The problem :
I get a null returned from `json_decode()` with the following JSON :

```
{
    "sku": "Yumeida/A-6083/Pink/28",
    "quantity": 1,
    "variation": "…, size:EU:28"
}
```

Upon testing, I discovered by removing the three dots in the `variation` key, the JSON returned an array as expected. But what I don't get is why the three dots caused this error?

I tried to `var_dump` the JSON before decoding and this is what I got:

```
string '[{"sku": "Yumeida/A-6083/Pink/28", "quantity": 1, "variation": "�, size:EU:28"}]' (length=80)
```

There's a "�" (Question mark in a black box). Is this a font problem? Or something else?

Additional information : The JSON was retrieved from MySQL database.

EDIT :
On https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect as recomended by a commenter shows that the three dots (`...`) was parsed as `HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS`

Comment: Perhaps an encoding issue, where the "three dots" are being interpreted as a single [ellipsis](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2026/index.htm)?

Comment: Is that your real JSON or have you manually transcribed it? `...` (U+002E : FULL STOP U+002E : FULL STOP U+002E : FULL STOP) and `…` (U+2026 : HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS) are significantly different.

Comment: You can get a bit of detail of the error by calling [json_last_error_msg()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php).

Comment: Hi, the JSON actually came from an Excel Spreadsheet which has the `...` on it and I used https://shancarter.github.io/mr-data-converter/ to convert it to JSON

Comment: I get `Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded` @IMSoP, Thank you. Currently looking for ways to fix it.

Comment: `"variation": "�` missing the ending quote

Comment: @PlanetCloud Your two samples don't match; the first has the key "Seller SKU", the second "sku". I'm sure this is because you've been trying to reproduce the error and narrow it down, but please can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve] - some JSON which, when parsed, will produce the same error you're seeing in your real code.

Comment: Paste the original JSON in [Unicode character inspector](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect). I bet you have an ellipsis encoded in some ANSI charset and JSON needs to use UTF-8.

Comment: @Jaquarh The value of that key is `"�, size:EU:28"`; there's no problem with quoting.

Comment: Looks to me like it should be `"variation": "�", "size": { "EU": 28 }` but if you say so @IMSoP

Comment: @IMSoP, Question has been editted.

Comment: Try this: json_decode(mb_convert_encoding($json, 'UTF-8'));

Comment: @TsV, Your solution gave me `?` instead of `�` but it does not crash my script. Is there any way to preserve the dots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current solution is from @TsV (https://stackoverflow.com/users/10111639/tsv).
Using the `mb_convert_encoding` function, the `�` now appears as regular `?` and did not crash the script.
I'm going to stick with this for now and if anyone knows how to preserve the dots, kindly post the answer.

Thank you everyone who tries to gave the answer.

```
https://stackoverflow.com/users/157957/imsop  
https://stackoverflow.com/users/1136527/alex-mcmillan  
https://stackoverflow.com/users/19068/quentin  
https://stackoverflow.com/users/13508/%C3%81lvaro-gonz%C3%A1lez
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set your default_charset to UTF-8:

default_charset = "utf-8"

You'll also want to make sure that your webserver is set to output UTF-8 if you're going to outputting UTF-8 encoded characters. In Apache this can be set by in the httpd.conf file:

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

After that your results like this:
string(69) "{ "variation": "…, size:EU:28","Tracking Code" : "LXRP-1868511636"}"

Comment: I had my charset se to UTF-8 and also found this `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');`, Do I also need this?

Answer (score -5):

I think the problem is that PHP considers the 3 dots a splat operator ([see here for more info](http://www.array99.com/code-stuff/12/three-dots-as-splat-operator)). So you may have to replace the ellipsis with something else or remove it entirely, with something like `str_replace('...','',$string)`

Comment: PHP is obviously (well it's PHP so maybe not that obviously) not going to try to evaluate the content as if it were PHP code.